# How can phabricator show content of .pdf and .docx on server side?

Tags: pdf, docx, phabricator

How can phabricator show content of .pdf and .docx on server side?

Now phabricator shows only the following message:

"This is a binary file. It is 77,613 bytes in length."

I must download raw file to see file content, it's inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option now to "View as PDF" which allows you to open the PDF on the server without downloading it. However, you still have to click on it to display; it does not show on the file-page.